# Identifying culprit for Firefox malfunction

Tags: firefox, web

In [my site](https://jellby.altervista.org/ebooks/index.php) I have some free (public domain, or with permission) ebooks, that can be read online with [epub.js](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/). It used to work fine in Firefox, but now I realize when I try to turn pages, a new copy of the book opens inside instead, and this can go on and on, e.g.:

[image]

I've verified this does not happen when I use a clean Firefox profile, but I can't figure out why my main profile is behaving like this. I've tried disabling uBlock Origin and the built-in tracking protection, and cleaning the site's cookies/data, to no avail. What other settings/add-ons could be causing this problem? I don't think I have any other add-on that should interact (Gesturefy, Simple Tab Groups, Add custom search engine...). Anyway, I have tried disabling all add-ons and it didn't fix it.

EDIT: Well, since the demo at https://futurepress.github.io/epubjs-reader seemed to be working correctly, I've managed to update the .js files in my site using the ones in the demo, and now it works (although the image sizes, like the cover, are worse than they were with the older version).

Comment: Temporarily disable all your addons and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Mokubai I tried that, no change.

Comment: If strange stuff happens, clear the cache. Not just for this site but entirely.

Comment: @DanielB Also tried it, still no change.

Comment: @Jellby I see the same problem on your site. Have you recently updated the version of epub.js? If you look in the console of the developer tools (press F12), it shows some warnings that you might want to take care of.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, I haven't changed it in some time (and last time I changed it, it worked, but that was probably with an older FF version). Note that a clean FF profile works fine too.

Comment: @Jellby I notice that if you [refresh Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) then the site works *once*. The next time you open FF, the site misbehaves. This is without changing any settings/preferences in FF after the refresh.

Comment: @Jellby On the off-chance that jQuery 1.11.3 is too old, could you use jQuery 2.2.4 as used in the Moby Dick example on the GitHub site you linked to? Although that wouldn't obviously explain why it works once.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Updating jQuery didn't help, and updating epub.js (from https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-reader or https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js) gave worse crashes (no display). I think I'm actually using version 0.2.13 (dated 2015), and somehow modified...